# Restart SCIM Provisioning Job via Logic App

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, scim

We have scim provisioning setup within a enterprise app. However we're currently having to run a scheduled task to restart it.

We want to create a logic app to do it for us at a set time. Any tips on this would be appreciated.

We have tried the following:

POST /servicePrincipals/{servicePrincipalId}/synchronization/jobs/{jobId}/restart

We have a service principal setup with a client secret for access.

Answer (score 0):

> Restart SCIM Provisioning Job via Logic App

You can firstly set a recurrence trigger as below:

[image]

Then you can add the http action:

[image]

Fill all the detailers (herders ,tokens) and post the url.
By this way you can do your requirement.